# Is it possible to make a sublime text editor plugin that highlights dynamic parts of a text?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3, highlighting, sublime-text-plugin

I want to make a plugin that colors the words based on their frequency in another document. I have the document or a database with the words and frequencies, i just want to be able to highlight them. It doesnt have to be in real time or anything like that, im just wondering if its possible at all.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I dont know what to try, to be honest. I was thinking maping a keyboard shortcut to run a script which generates a custom theme or something like that, but the regex would be very difficult to make dynamically.

Comment: Maybe take inspiration from [ColorHighlighter](https://github.com/Monnoroch/ColorHighlighter/blob/master/ColorHighlighter.py), it seems to [generate a theme](https://github.com/Monnoroch/ColorHighlighter/blob/master/ColorHighlighter.py#L189-L221) on-the-fly.

Comment: You can do it in CudaText. Also in python. API exists: look at wiki for `attr` function.

Comment: yes, this is possible. On which problems are you stuck?